# Youtube iframe シークバークリック時にイベント発生

Tags: javascript, jquery

画像のような場面で、シークバーをクリックした時にイベントを発生したいと思い、下記のようなコードを書きましたが、うまく動作しません。
シークバークリック時にイベントを発生させる方法はありますでしょうか？

```
$(function () {
    $(".ytp-progress-bar-padding").click(function () {
        console.log("----")
    });
});
```

[image: 画像1]

Answer (score 0):

iFrame内なのでその書き方ではiframe内のタグの指定になっていないではないでしょうか

iframe内のタグを読み込む場合は下記のようにする必要があるかと思います
https://teratail.com/questions/40316

```
$(window).on("load", function(e){
  $("#iframe").contents().find("body").on("click", function(e){
    console.log("click");
  });
});
```

またシークバー移動時になどyoutubeのアクションと連動して動作をしたい場合
apiを使うのが一般的かと思います。
今回のケースで使えるかはわからないですが、ご検討してみてください。
https://so-zou.jp/web-app/tech/web-api/google/youtube/player-api/iframe.htm#status